# "mut" location is unintuitive but works. Why?

Tags: rust, mutability

In order to learn Rust I'm just writing trivial programs. Here I've written a LinkedList with an insert function that adds nodes to the end of the list. The function works as expected but I don't understand why my `mut` positioning in the struct is working as intended. Here's the code:

```rust
struct LinkedNode<'a, T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<&'a mut LinkedNode<'a, T>>
}

impl<'a, T> LinkedNode<'a, T> {
    fn new(val: T, next: Option<&'a mut LinkedNode<'a, T>>) -> LinkedNode<'a, T> {
        LinkedNode { val, next }
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, node: &'a mut LinkedNode<'a, T>) 
        where T: Display {
        let mut i = &mut self.next;
        while let Some(n) = i  {
            i = &mut n.next;
        }
        *i = Some(node);
    }
}
```

Everything makes sense except this part:

```rust
struct LinkedNode<'a, T> {
    ...
    next: Option<&'a mut LinkedNode<'a, T>>
}
```

What I'm mutating here is `next` and not the `&'a LinkedNode<'a, T>` within it.

I would have expected to need the following code instead:

```rust
struct LinkedNode<'a, T> {
    ...
    next: mut Option<&'a LinkedNode<'a, T>>
}
```

but this doesn't even compile. It gives me this error instead:

```
error: expected type, found keyword `mut`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:11
  |
3 | struct LinkedNode<'a, T> {
  |        ---------- while parsing this struct
4 |     val: T,
5 |     next: mut Option<&'a LinkedNode<'a, T>>
  |           ^^^ expected type
```

Can someone explain what's going on here to me please?

Comment: You can always mutate `val` or `next` if the `LinkedNode` is mutable, so you don't need any annotation like `next: mut ...`. In contrast `&` and `&mut` are different *types* that express what you can do with the reference; if you want to mutate what is being referenced, you need `&mut`.

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you provide example code to clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two meanings for `mut`.

In `&mut`, it means a mutable, exclusive reference. An `&mut` value can change the contents it points to and give out `&mut` references to itself and its contents.

In patterns, like `let mut x = y;`, `mut` means that the binding is mutable. This value itself is mutable, and can give out `&mut` references to itself and its contents. There's also `ref mut`, which creates an `&mut` binding, but that doesn't apply here. You can also have `&mut` in a pattern, like `let &mut x = y`, which destructures the reference, copying the value. This also doesn't apply here.

Having a bare `mut` in a type, like you tried above, doesn't make any sense. Immutable and mutable owned values (not references) are the same type. The only type-level `mut` is `&mut`.

It might make theoretical sense to have something like this.

```rs
struct LinkedNode<'a, T> {
    val: T,
    mut next: Option<&'a mut LinkedNode<'a, T>>
}
```

However, this is not allowed either, because in rust, the mutability of each member is inherited from the owner of the whole struct.

```rs
let a = LinkedNode { val: 1, next: None }; // immutable
a.val = 2 // does not compile

let mut b = LinkedNode { val: 3, next: None }; // mutable
b.val = 4 // compiles
```

If you struct was this.

```rs
struct LinkedNode<'a, T> {
    val: T,
    next: Option<&'a LinkedNode<'a, T>>
}
```

Then you couldn't insert more than one node because you can't get a mutable reference to the node in `next`, regardless of the mutability of `next` itself.

Also, [linked lists in rust are not a trivial program](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: I think you need to explicitly mention what `mut` means when it appears on the left hand side of an assignment versus the right hand side. But I more or less understand what you mean

Comment: @Qwertyzw I added a part about `&mut` in patterns. You can't have `mut` without `&` on the right-hand side of an assignment (the expression), nor in the middle (the type), only the left-hand side (the pattern).